# using remote validation jquery plugin option only on blur event

Tags: jquery, validation, plugins

i am using validation jQuery plugin and its remote option for check whether user enters only Persian characters in a textbox . my code and php script work fine but my problem is remote option fires whenever user type a character in textbox while i want to do that only on blur(losses focus) on the text box . this is a part of my code:

```
    $('#regForm').validate({
                    rules:{
                        name            :   {
                            required:true,
                            remote    : {
                                url :   'check',
                                type:   'post'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                messages:{
                    name            :   {
                        required    :   "this is Required",
                        remote      :   "Please enter Persian character "
                    }
                }
    });
```

what is solution?

Comment: On the options. That is `$('#regForm').validate({onkeyup: false, ...});`

Comment: yes! it works fine. tnx Shef:)

Comment: Great, posting it as an answer so you can accept it and mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't want your fields to validate on `keyup` event, then you would have to use:

```
$('selector').validate({
    onkeyup: false, 
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Block `keyup` for only the remote call, not the entire form:

```
$('selector').validate({
    rules:{
        name : {
            required:true,
            remote : {
              onkeyup: false,
              url : 'check',
              type: 'post'
          }
        }
      }
    ...
});
```